# DevExtreme's DataGrid exportToPDF displays gibberish when used on a table with Russian values in it

Tags: jspdf, devextreme, jspdf-autotable, devextreme-angular

When I try to export to PDF DataGrid with Russian values in it, it displays gibberish in this new PDF file even though I managed to set a proper font (PTSans) for jsPDF and when you print just random text it is working fine…

So is there a way to configure table to PDF to display proper Russian?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I suddenly found a solution :D

If anyone will ever have this problem again, this is how you solve it:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

const font = "../../../assets/fonts/PTSans-Regular.ttf" // path to .ttf file
doc.addFont(font, "PTSans-Regular", "normal");

exportDataGridToPdf({
  jsPDFDocument: doc,
  component: grid,
  autoTableOptions: {
    styles: {
      font: 'PTSans-Regular' // this is a part I forgot about before
    }
  }
}).then(() => {
  doc.save(filename);
})
```

Basically you need to set up font for your language in jsPdf as well as set up the same in styles for jsPDF-autoTable options.

Huge thanks to Alisher from DevExpress Support whose answer helped me to figure it out.